# Десериализация Spring Data Page из JSON с помощью Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring

Имеем JSON сгенерированный Спрингом. Это Spring Data Page

```
{
  "content" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "create_date" : "2016.01.12 12:24:06",
    "last_modified_date" : null,
    "prop" : [ ]
  }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "create_date" : "2016.01.12 12:24:28",
    "last_modified_date" : null,
    "prop" : [ ]
  }, {
    "id" : 3,
    "create_date" : "2016.01.12 12:24:29",
    "last_modified_date" : null,
    "prop" : [ ]
  } ],
  "last" : true,
  "total_pages" : 1,
  "total_elements" : 3,
  "size" : 50,
  "number" : 0,
  "sort" : null,
  "first" : true,
  "number_of_elements" : 3
}
```

Видим тут три простеньких объекта на одной страничке.
Вопрос: Как из этого джейсона принять Page T> с помощью Spring Rest Template(желательно)

Comment: Вы получаете в ответе такой JSON? Если да - можно попробовать через restTemplate.exchange, с указанием в типе ответа заранее подготовленный класс, описывающий структуру ответа. В результате получите ResponceEntity<Ваш_класс>. Зачем именно Page?

Comment: Это стандартный класс спринга, имеет методы getTotal(), getSize, getLast() и так далее. Пока что тупо переписали этот класс, добавили вручную что надо и пользуемся. Но хотелось бы не костыльный способ =)